# HTML select only outputs a few things

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a select using https://tom-select.js.org/ and when I give it the options it only shows me some of them

```js
new TomSelect("#select", {
  create: true,
  sortField: {
    field: "text",
    direction: "asc",
  },
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 pb-4">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <select id="select" placeholder="Law Area..." autocomplete="off" style="width:500px">
            <option value="">Law Area</option>
            <option value="Advertising & Product Regulatory">Advertising & Product Regulatory</option>
            <option value="Banking & Finance">Banking & Finance</option>
            <option value="Banking Litigation">Banking Litigation</option>
            <option value="Blockchain & Smart Contracts">Blockchain & Smart Contracts</option>
            <option value="Capital Markets">Capital Markets</option>
            <option value="Charities & Not-for-Profits">Charities & Not-for-Profits</option>
            <!-- -----CUT FOR SIZE----- -->
            <option value="Data Privacy & Protection">Data Privacy & Protection</option>
            <option value="Business Law">Business Law</option>
            <option value="Conveyancing & Support">Conveyancing & Support</option>
            <option value="Immigration Law">Immigration Law</option>
            <option value="Personal Injury">Personal Injury</option>
            <option value="Wills & Trust, Estate">Wills & Trust, Estate</option>
            <option value="Planning, and Probate">Planning, and Probate</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any limit of how many elements you can add in  ?

Comment: Surely the section is scrollable, rather than not including them at all? Your example seems to show the browser default select for me, can you edit it to display the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion there is a limit in tom-select set maxOptions to null and it works

Comment: Please add a code example displaying how to set the attribute to `null`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).